# quickly load in page_load event

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have more than 25 procedure to execute on page_load

it works fine, but it takes longer time to load all events

I have procedure llike below

```
GetAllVacation();
GetOvertime();
GetTodaysAbsentees();
GetAssignment();
..
..
```

So on.....

I takes lot of time to load all procedure

I want to load one by one, using multi threading or Jquery AJAX anything

Oneprocedure executed successfully, data must be displayed.

one by one execution,

How can i do so...

Regards

Comment: And the question is? Have you tried something yourself? You said yourself the correct approach: AJAX..

Comment: jQuery, MS-Ajax and Multi Threading are in fact your options.

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading improves user experience, but doesn't actually speed up a process.  In this case you need to look at all the data you're pulling and try to figure out which can be deferred until later.  For example, you might be able to avoid calling GetAllVacation() until/unless the user does something that requires that data.